# How to check if a string is a numeric or not for example "1" is but "x" is not

Tags: java, operating-system

```
static int Add() {
  Instindex++;
  if ()

    int a = Integer.parseInt(instructions[Instindex]);
  else
    ReadInstruction();
  Instindex++;
  if (x == (int) x)
    int b = Integer.parseInt(instructions[Instindex]);
  else
    ReadInstruction();
  return a + b;
}
```

instindex is an index for instructions array whis is array for parsed program I wanna check if the element I'm at its index is a numeric so I can perform the addittion normally else I'm gonna call my system caller

Comment: so, Integer.parseInt doesn't tell you that "x" isn't numeric?

Comment: [Easy way to format your code online](https://codebeautify.org/javaviewer)

Comment: Integer.parseInt tells me but if its not a numeric it will cause an exception

Comment: So why don't you make a method, which catches the exception and returns false, and returns true if exception wasn't thrown?

Comment: To emphasize - an exception does not invariably mean that you've got a bug in your code. Exceptions are tools to be used.

Comment: @iggy not a recommended use, though.

Comment: @AdhamEl-sheikh have you tried regex?

Comment: Why not recommended?  Parsing a string purported to be a integer, and throwing an exception when it doesn't contain valid digits, is a perfectly decent way to find and report whether a stiring is an integer.  See the accepted answer for that approach. Using a regex for trivial jobs like that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check like this:

```
boolean isNumeric(String str){
    try{
        Integer.parseInt(str);
        return true;
    }catch (NumberFormatException e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
  return str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");  //match a number with optional '-' and decimal.
}
```

try this